# Minifying an ExtJS application using UglifyJS?

Tags: extjs, minify

Is it possible to minify an ExtJS 4 MVC style application using a third party tool like UglifyJS?

I've tried compressing each file in the app into a single file, but the ExtJS loader then reports that it can't find the files to load.

I am aware that Sencha has an official build tool, but I am trying to get the minify to work with a more industry standard tool that is easier to deploy on servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible to use UglifyJS manually but I'd recommend going with Sencha Cmd. Besides JS compression, it deals with many other tasks: dependency tracking, package management, theme building, etc. It's not that all of these are required for Ext JS application but Sencha Cmd will definitely save you a lot of time and pain, and the bigger your app is, the more pronounced the effect will be down the road.

Just my 2¢ anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the advice. I asked the question mainly I am curious about what is different between Sencha Cmd compressed JavaScript vs UglifyJS compressed stuff but I haven't had time to do proper research on it.

Comment: I have only limited knowledge of Cmd so far (I'm not working on it directly), but from what I know minifiers are configurable and you can change default YUI compressor to UglifyJS if you like it more.